# C# Trying to get a sum to work with different variables through a button

Tags: c#, variables, sum

I am trying to make a sum in c# but i keep getting these errors. 
by pressing the + button i pretty much want the numbers to be summed up in a label.

Thanks in advance.

here's my code.

```
private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 a = 10;
    double b = 20.50;
    double c = 50.10;
    Int32 d = 20;
    labelSum.Text = (a+b+c+d);
}
```

Comment: `keep getting these errors`  What are the errors?

Comment: Append `.ToString();` to the last line

Comment: Post the error message. But first, read it and try to understand it. It probably says something like *"Cannot implicitly convert type `'double'` to `'string'`"*. If you don't understand it, search google for that error message. If you are *still* stuck, post here the actual error message, how you've tried to solve it, and what part you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're using `Int32` and not just `int`.

Also, try converting the sum to a string:

```
labelSum.Text = (a+b+c+d).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Text` property is of type `String` while your expression will return a numeric data type not `String` so, the right hand side should be returning the same type what the left hand of expression is having when assigning.

Just convert the result of sum to string by calling `ToString()` :

```
labelSum.Text = (a+b+c+d).ToString();
```

or like:

```
labelSum.Text = Convert.ToString(a+b+c+d);
```